# ActionScript - Save webcam video to local disk without using AIR or FMS

Tags: actionscript, video, save, webcam, local

I would like to save a webcam captured video to the local disk using AS. The application is running in a standalone Flashplayer 10. I can save pictures from ByteArrays using file.save, but I can't find a way for doing this with video.

There is a nice implementation for that using AS and AIR at http://www.joristimmerman.be/wordpress/2008/12/18/flvrecorder-record-to-flv-using-air/. I don't want to have to install AIR before running the app. Any ideas?

Thanks, Basti

Answer (score 1):

Flash is designed to be secure, so you won't be able to save anything but SharedObject data on local storage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible up to the current Flash Player (10) to save video directly to the local disc. You can only save pictures to the local disc.